# PHP/MySQLi POO fetch_array on null

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a function to search for users within my database, but does not work correctly throwing the following error, I have a good time trying different methods but I manage to make it work so I recuerro to you hoping that you can help

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on null
```

That is the mistake that pulls me on the page and this is my code

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="usuario" type="text" class="INPUT-GENERAL" placeholder="Buscar usuario">
    <button class="BOTON-GENERAL" type="submit">Buscar</button>
  </form>
  <?php
    $Usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    if ($Usuario!="") {
      $Busqueda = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".real_escape_string($Usuario)."' ");
    }
    while ($Resultado = $Busqueda->fetch_array()) {
  ?>
  <?php
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=./usuarios.php?usuario='.$Resultado['username'].'" />';
  ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: check your query to see if it generates any results at all

Comment: Do you get this error after you submit the form, or when you first load the page with the form on it?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php
    $Usuario = real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    if (!empty($Usuario)) {$Busqueda = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".$Usuario."' ");
    }
if($Busqueda){
    while ($Resultado = $Busqueda->fetch_array()) {echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=./usuarios.php?usuario='.$Resultado['username'].'" />';} 
}
?>
```

and avoid msqli connections use pdo next time msqli allmost finish